# The reason we use "using statement" in the following code?

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework, using

I can't completely understand the reason why we should use "`using`" block here

the following code is used to show two tables name "genre" and "review" from the database using EF

it is the code :

C#

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)    
{    
    using (PlanetWroxEntities myEntities = new PlanetWroxEntities())    
    {
        var authorizedReviews = from review in myEntities.Reviews    
                                where review.Authorized == true    
                                orderby review.CreateDateTime descending    
                                select review;

        GridView1.DataSource = authorizedReviews.ToList();

        GridView1.DataBind();    
    }    
}
```

here is some explanation from the author :

> After the model has been generated, you can execute LINQ queries
>   against it to get data out of the underlying database. To access the
>   data, you need an instance of the `DbContext` class, which is the base
>   class for the `PlanetWroxEntities` class. That instance is created
>   inside the Using block in the code. A Using block (using in C#) is
>   used to wrap code that **creates a variable that must be disposed of**
>   (cleared from memory) as soon as you’re done with it. Because the
>   `myEntities` variable holds a (scarce) connection to the SQL Server
>   database, it’s a good idea to wrap the code that uses it in a Using
>   block, so the object is destroyed at the end of the block and the
>   **connection is released.** This `myEntities` object then exposes your data (such as reviews and genres) that you can use in a query:

I have two question :

1- Why we should get rid of the variable ? is it because it takes memory space? or is it because it holds a connection to the SQL Server database so we don't need object but just the connection?

2- What does it means  *"connection is released"?* if the connection is part of object why it didn't destroy too?

Comment: myEntities  will be available only inside the using block, and it is cleared after it..dont need to close or disconnect the connection..+

Comment: why the connection survived if the object destroy?

Comment: That was my theoretical knowledge, Good question

Comment: Post the test code

Comment: That was the test code . why I don't understand is that last sentence where he says "it’s a good idea to wrap the code that uses it in a Using block, so the object is destroyed at the end of the block and the connection is released. This myEntities object then exposes your data (such as reviews and genres) that you can use in a query:"

Comment: what does it mean the connection is released when the object is already destroyed and then how a destroyed object can expose data?

Comment: This is just my theory [-[ Connection is hard coded i guess, there is difference in being connected and ready to connect, for ready to connect only config and an object to the database is needed, but when connection is initialised an open and some info is stored in the object, that extra info and status and stuff are released when the using block is fininshed execution

Comment: @mohsen The object is not "destroyed" until some undetermined time after it's no longer referenced by your code.  It's not destroyed immediately.  Only when the garbage collection manager finally gets around to destroying the object will it call the Dispose method to release the database connection back to the database pool.  See my answer for more details.

Comment: A good rule of thumb is: if something implements `IDisposable`, you should probably use a `using` statement to clean up after yourself, even if you don't fully understand what kind of unmanaged resource the object is holding.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1) The reason for the using statement is to ensure that the `myEntities.Dispose()` method is called as soon as the code inside the using statement completes.  This is necessary since the `PlanetWroxEntities` class' base class is a `DbContext` which holds a connection to the database.

Database connections are a precious resource that are obtained from the database connection pool and there are only a finite number of connections available that your whole application must share.  If you don't call `Dispose` on the `myEntities` object as soon as you are done with it via the using statement (or some other manner) then the `myEntities` object will continue to tie up that database connection for some undetermined amount of time until the garbage collection code from the .net memory manager gets around to reclaiming the memory that is held by the `myEntities` object that is no longer in use.

The memory manager will at that time calls the dispose method.  As soon as the Dispose method is called the database connection is released from the object and returned to the database connection pool where it can be obtained by other parts of your application when you make a call to get a database connection (for example when you create other instances of the `PlanetWroxEntities` class.)

The purpose of the using statement is to have the `Dispose` method called as soon as you are done with the object so that in this case the database connection is returned to the pool right away.

2) It means the database connection is released by your application and is returned to the database connection pool where it is now available to be obtained by other parts of your application.  Here is one resource that talks more about connection pooling, it will give you more background on what is going on under the hood: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8xx3tyca.aspx

Under the hood the using statement is implemented as a finally statement.  So this code:

```
using (PlanetWroxEntities myEntities = new PlanetWroxEntities())    
{
    var authorizedReviews = from review in myEntities.Reviews    
                            where review.Authorized == true    
                            orderby review.CreateDateTime descending    
                            select review;

    GridView1.DataSource = authorizedReviews.ToList();

    GridView1.DataBind();    
}
```

becomes

```
PlanetWroxEntities myEntities; 
try{
    myEntities = new PlanetWroxEntities();
    var authorizedReviews = from review in myEntities.Reviews    
                            where review.Authorized == true    
                            orderby review.CreateDateTime descending    
                            select review;

    GridView1.DataSource = authorizedReviews.ToList();

    GridView1.DataBind();   

} finally{
    myEntities.Dispose();
}
```

In the old days of C# we always had to write the finally statement ourselves to dispose of disposable objects so that their unmanaged resources were released.  But later the using statement was introduced in C# to make it easier to accomplish this.  Even today, you can write the finally statement yourself if you prefer, but most people love the using statement.

For more information see https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yh598w02.aspx

Comment: thanks. it was the best and throughout explanation.in another word "using" act as a timer that releases a connection after the object is done with it . does implement "using" in the namespace where other "using" are lead to the same result as you described?or it should be used with instance class like above example? in the book I'm reading it is not that much explained, I know it's not related to this topic but is it possible for you to introduce me to some books and resources on ASP and net?

Comment: Thanks. The using statement doesn't act as a timer it is another way to write a finally statement, kinda.  I will update my answer to show that.  Using is only used when instantiating a class and specifically one that implements the Dispose method.  SO is a great resource for learning and google is your best friend. That said, I like programming books from apress, microsoft press and SAMS.  tweet me at @dotnetcore and I can give more recommendations.

Answer (score 2):

`PlanetWroxEntities` implements `IDisposable`.

`IDisposable` is implemented by classes that hold native resources that need to be released when you're done with an object.

So, to answer #1: You should "get rid" of the variable as soon as possible so you're not holding on to native resources that could be released back to the system.

The `using` statement ensures that `Dispose()` is called properly when you're done using your Entities. You're not only releasing the connection, but any other native resources as well.

Comment: what is the native resource ? in relation to proceeding example?

Comment: by "native resource" @justin means "non managed resource" and in this case that's a database connection.

Answer (score 1):

Why we should get rid of the variable?

> is it because it takes memory space?

Yes

> or is it because it holds a connection to the SQL Server database so
>   we don't need object but just the connection?

The job (populating the grid) is done within `GridView1.DataBind();`

You don't need the object or the connection after that.

> What does it means "connection is released"? if the connection is part of object why it didn't destroy too?

The object `myEntities` is destroyed, together with it's connection to the database.

Normally the entities returned by EF queries can generate further database queries. This is called *lazy loading*.

Wrapping EF queries in a using statement prevents lazy loading from happening - giving you the certain knowledge that database queries are only happening within the repository.

Comment: thanks, I got it .And AFA I heard  lazy loading means sub-objects are not loaded until you explicitly tell them to.and properties of the sub-objects you query are null. don't you think your definition is wrong or at least you should have said:"Normally the entities returned by EF queries can generate further database queries if we explicitly want them?so normally they don't generate the  further database. or am I wrong?

Comment: Lazy loading means loaded on first use (e.g. when you test them for null). So `if (x.SubObject == null)` would access the database at that point - if the database connection still exists.